# download file in flutter

Tags: download, flutter

i make a flutter application, first i display all information about pdf file, and it is include the url of the file, comming form Restfull API, everything work good, but i want to download this file when user click on it, i try this:

```
 onTap: () async {
                                // downloadFile(snapshot.data[index].file);
                                Dio dio = new Dio();
                                Directory dir =
                                    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                                String path = dir.path;
                                await dio.download(
                                    snapshot.data[index].file, path);
                              },
```

snapshot.data[index].file, path is the right path or file that come from api, but it is not work, and give me an error with (path) in this code

```
await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String path = dir.path;

this is my error log:

E/flutter (26482): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (26482): FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/data/com.example.mis/app_flutter' (OS Error: Is a
directory, errno = 21)
E/flutter (26482): #0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:647:7)
E/flutter (26482): #1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:491:5)
E/flutter (26482): #2      Dio.download (package:dio/src/dio.dart:212:20)
E/flutter (26482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26482): #3      MaterialsState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:mis/courses/materials.dart:121:47)
E/flutter (26482): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26482): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
E/flutter (26482): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
E/flutter (26482): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter (26482): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter (26482): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter (26482): #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (26482): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:184:20)
E/flutter (26482): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
E/flutter (26482): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
E/flutter (26482): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (26482): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter (26482): #15     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:159:13)
E/flutter (26482): #16     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:113:5)
```

is there any other method to download file? or even to just open it? thank you very much

Comment: Please post the error log. Yes, there is another method where you can use [flutter_downloader] plugin specifically designed for creating and managing download tasks. Supports iOS and Android.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_downloader

Comment: Thank you, i will try, i will append error in post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995621/how-to-download-a-file-and-store-it-in-downloads-folder-using-flutter/57997334#57997334

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone else needs this.
The problem is that you didn't pass a file path as parameter but passed a directory.

```
await dio.download(snapshot.data[index].file, path+'/fileName.pdf');
```

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use plugin File support on flutter https://pub.dev/packages/file_support

```
Future<File> downloadFile async{
File file =await FileSupport(url:"http://test.com/.mp4");
 return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [flutter cache manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

using this code to get your file:

```
 String url = 'https://fileUrl';
File file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

then you can use 'file' to do what you want.