# How to download a file and store it in Downloads folder using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building an App using Flutter 1.10.3 and I'm having difficulties downloading images to the Downloads folder of the device.

Is there an option to do so without using any 3rd-part libraries?

Comment: Is it fine if using dio ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati that's fine

Comment: you implement download file functionality as i answer ?

Comment: @Amit the implementation you wrote works, but I was hoping for a shorter implementation. Maybe I'm used to PHP's function `file_get_content`. It sounds wrong to me to add 4 packages and write dozens lines of code for a simple task. Therefore, I upvoted your question, but I can't accept it yet

Comment: It's okay, but that 4 package is basic necessity, anyway best of luck, if you found better solution please add it as new answer.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati sure thing, thank you for your help :) well explained and might help lots of other people

Comment: What's restricting you from using 3rd party libraries? If you write the download code your self that's an additional maintenance cost. You need to write tests as well. I agree that some libraries could suddenly be abandoned but that's uncommon.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader is a good place to start for anyone who's got no restrictions.

Answer (score 19):

Add few required dependencies, I have a test demo with android only. please review `file_utils` and `path_provider` while you implement in IOS device.

```
  dio: ^3.0.0

  path_provider: ^1.3.0

  simple_permissions: ^0.1.9

  file_utils: ^0.1.3
```

**Note:** `simple_permissions` is disconnected please use this dependency `permission_handler`

You are required to add permissions on the android manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Sample code:

```
  import 'dart:io';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
  import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';
  import 'package:file_utils/file_utils.dart';
  import 'dart:math';

  void main() => runApp(Downloader());

  class Downloader extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
          title: "File Downloader",
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: FileDownloader(),
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        );
  }

  class FileDownloader extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _FileDownloaderState createState() => _FileDownloaderState();
  }

  class _FileDownloaderState extends State<FileDownloader> {

    final imgUrl = "https://images6.alphacoders.com/683/thumb-1920-683023.jpg";
    bool downloading = false;
    var progress = "";
    var path = "No Data";
    var platformVersion = "Unknown";
    Permission permission1 = Permission.WriteExternalStorage;
    var _onPressed;
    static final Random random = Random();
    Directory externalDir;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      downloadFile();
    }


    Future<void> downloadFile() async {
      Dio dio = Dio();
      bool checkPermission1 =
          await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
      // print(checkPermission1);
      if (checkPermission1 == false) {
        await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(permission1);
        checkPermission1 = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(permission1);
      }
      if (checkPermission1 == true) {
        String dirloc = "";
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          dirloc = "/sdcard/download/";
        } else {
          dirloc = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
        }

        var randid = random.nextInt(10000);

        try {
          FileUtils.mkdir([dirloc]);
          await dio.download(imgUrl, dirloc + randid.toString() + ".jpg",
              onReceiveProgress: (receivedBytes, totalBytes) {
            setState(() {
              downloading = true;
              progress =
                  ((receivedBytes / totalBytes) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
            });
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }

        setState(() {
          downloading = false;
          progress = "Download Completed.";
          path = dirloc + randid.toString() + ".jpg";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          progress = "Permission Denied!";
          _onPressed = () {
            downloadFile();
          };
        });
      }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('File Downloader'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: downloading
                ? Container(
                    height: 120.0,
                    width: 200.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Downloading File: $progress',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(path),
                      MaterialButton(
                        child: Text('Request Permission Again.'),
                        onPressed: _onPressed,
                        disabledColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        height: 40.0,
                        minWidth: 100.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  )));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: My project is migrated in Android X but the plugin simple_permission give error I found that this plugin is not migrated in android x

Comment: It would be great you apply manually permission and test this code, if it work for you then use any other permission plugin.

Comment: I used permission_handler.

Comment: This works well, but it does not show a notification when the download is complete. Any idea how to go about doing that?

Comment: Works fine on Android 8 (Oreo) (once permission lib is changed as per Tarun) but much more code required for Android 10 (no writing allowed to download folder). I have working code for this in Java, but no idea how to do it in Dart.

Comment: Oops, ignore my comment above. For Android 10, don't use ```/sdcard/download/``` but use the 'else' case ```(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path```

Comment: `https://pub.dev/packages/simple_permissions` package has been discontinued and not supports NULL SAFETY. Not recommend to anyone.

Answer (score 9):

If you control the server, another option is to let the user's system handle the download. On the server you add a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header to the response. In nginx you can do this with the `add_header` directive in your sites-enabled config file:

```
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
```

More notes about that [here](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-add_header).

Then on the Flutter side you can use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package to initiate the download:

```
await launch('https://www.example.com/my_file.pdf');
```

This will hand over the downloading to the browser installed on the phone. And the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header will tell the browser that it is to be downloaded instead of displayed or played.

This solution is pretty painless, though it doesn't give you control about where the file is downloaded to.

Comment: This is a good approach, but is there any way to capture the download percentage?

Comment: @Zorro, I wrote an article about that [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-show-download-progress-in-a-flutter-app-8810e294acbd).

Comment: @Suragch Your article is viewable only for upgraded accounts in Medium.

Comment: @AnoopThiruonam, Thanks for the notice. [Here is the friend link.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-show-download-progress-in-a-flutter-app-8810e294acbd?sk=b38f79aa4ee9dec83699f18d6fd0aaf4)

Answer (score 0):

use [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) have:

- Download notifications complete on android
- Download queue
- Download status
- Download process

view example on [github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader)