# How to download all files in a folder from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get all files from one folder/directory from Firebase Storage.

I'm using Flutter with firebase_storage dependency. I successfully downloaded one file in a folder but can't figure out how to download all files. If anyone knows how to do it, please help me.

Comment: This has recently been added to Firebase Cloud Storage, but it is not in the Flutter plugin yet. You could create a pull request adding the functionality using the [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) and [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files) features. Notice that there is an [existing issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/83#issue-488783835) about this.

Comment: Look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995621/how-to-download-a-file-and-store-it-in-downloads-folder-using-flutter/57997334#57997334