# How can I download file using flutter dio?

Tags: android, ios, http, flutter, dart

I want to downlaod file using url with help of flutter `Dio`.

```
  final imgUrl = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
  var dio = Dio();
```

```
RaisedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: (){
                    download2(dio, imgUrl, "./example/boo2.pdf");
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.file_download,color: Colors.white,),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  label: Text('Dowload Invoice')
              )
```

```
 Future download2(Dio dio, String url, String savePath) async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get(
        url,
        onReceiveProgress: showDownloadProgress,
        //Received data with List<int>
        options: Options(
            responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
            followRedirects: false,
            validateStatus: (status) { return status < 500; }
            ),
      );
      print(response.headers);
      File file = File(savePath);
      var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
      // response.data is List<int> type
      raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
      await raf.close();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void showDownloadProgress(received, total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
    }
  }
```

i am gettng this error.

OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13flutter

Comment: Thanks! Your `download2` function saved me a few minutes!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider to get Temporary Directory

code snippet

```
RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                  String fullPath = tempDir.path + "/boo2.pdf'";
                  print('full path ${fullPath}');

                  download2(dio, imgUrl, fullPath);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.file_download,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                label: Text('Dowload Invoice'))
```

working demo

[image]
[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

final imgUrl =
    "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
var dio = Dio();

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future download2(Dio dio, String url, String savePath) async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get(
        url,
        onReceiveProgress: showDownloadProgress,
        //Received data with List<int>
        options: Options(
            responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
            followRedirects: false,
            validateStatus: (status) {
              return status < 500;
            }),
      );
      print(response.headers);
      File file = File(savePath);
      var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
      // response.data is List<int> type
      raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
      await raf.close();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void showDownloadProgress(received, total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                  String fullPath = tempDir.path + "/boo2.pdf'";
                  print('full path ${fullPath}');

                  download2(dio, imgUrl, fullPath);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.file_download,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                label: Text('Dowload Invoice')),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if I want to store this file in my download folder how can I give path  ?

Comment: Mean any particular location where I want to store the downloaded file.

Comment: You can not do any folder , most of folder in Android newer version is protected. You can create a folder inside getTemporaryDirectory()

Comment: But downloaded file is not display in my phone.

Comment: But Using android studio device explorer It is visible.

Comment: You can reference this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995621/how-to-download-a-file-and-store-it-in-downloads-folder-using-flutter

Comment: Sir, this solution is not working because the plugin simple_permissions is not migrated in android x and my project is already migrated in android x.

Comment: The error happens if you don't give permissions to write external storage

Comment: if you want store your file in your download folder: 
 await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                          ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

                  String fullPath = "$path/FolderName/yourfile.pdf";

Comment: Any update in this as given solution is not working

Answer (score 4):

You have to add permissions.

For Android: in AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
>   <manifest...
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> ```

pubspec.yaml

> ext_storage: ^1.0.3

your.dart

> ```
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     getPermission();
>     super.initState();
>   }
>
>   //get storage permission
>   void getPermission() async {
>     await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
>   }
> ```

Comment: can you detail this answer mor please ? 

Answer (score 0):

I cannot save a pdf into this path

```dart
final directory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
```

And finally able to save the file to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/` using below method to check if `download` or `downloads` path is exist and prioritized:

```dart
Future<String> _getPath() async {
    String directory;
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      directory = (await getDownloadsDirectory())?.path ??
          (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    } else {
      directory = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/';
      var dirDownloadExists = true;
      dirDownloadExists = await Directory(directory).exists();
      if (!dirDownloadExists) {
        directory = '/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/';
        dirDownloadExists = await Directory(directory).exists();
        if (!dirDownloadExists) {
          directory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
        }
      }
    }
    return directory;
}
```

And no problem with your `Future<void> download2()` method.

I did't use this permission as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Because starting android 10, storage permission marked as deprecated [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#faq), and use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE instead.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

notes:

flutter stable: 3.16.3

dio: ^5.4.0

permission_handler: ^11.1.0