# download a text file in flutter

Tags: flutter, download

I'm trying to download a .txt file from the web in flutter is there any way?
it would be helpful if it works also for Google drive.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) flutter to download files

```
response = await dio.download("url", "storagePath");
```

downloading from google drive your url would look something like this

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?alt=media&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

here is a link to SO answer with more details on using [dio to download files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624159/10409567)