# save a temp file to download file Android/IOS in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-packages

I have a question, I am using Path-provider to generate a path for a new generated PDF file from my App… but path provider is storing the file in the App folder & after closing the app the file will be deleted, I am using `getExternalStorageDirectory`… how can I save that file to downloads when selected.
Anybody can help me?
just small explanation... the PDF file will be viewed from the App using
flutter_full_pdf_viewer
then from that page I need to let the user select if he wants to save the file or close the hall file.
This is the code for the file save

```
  try {
    final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String documentPath = dir.path;
    fullPath = "$documentPath/$fileName";
    final file = File('$fullPath');
    await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
    print('XXXXXXXXX$fileName');
    return file;
  } catch (e) {
    // print('we have a problem');
  }
  print(fullPath);
}
```

And this is the PDFViewer page code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: PDFViewerScaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('PDF page'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                onPressed: () {
                  Share.shareFiles(
                    ['$path'],
                  );
                  print('iiiiiiiiiiiiii$path');
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
          path: path,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

============================================================================
after I modified the code now it looks like this for the PDF_save Page (for Methods)

```
Future<bool> saveFolder(String fileName) async {
  Directory directory;
  try {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
        directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String newPath = "";
        print('ZZZZZZZZzzzzZZZZz$directory');
        List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
        for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
          String folder = paths[x];
          if (folder != "Android") {
            newPath += "/" + folder;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        newPath = newPath + "/SAMApp";
        directory = Directory(newPath);
        print('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$newPath');
        print('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$fileName');
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
        directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    File saveFile = File(directory.path + "/$fileName");
    if (!await directory.exists()) {
      await directory.create(recursive: true);
    }
    if (await directory.exists()) {
      // await dio.download(saveFile.path, onReceiveProgress: (value1, value2) {
      //   setState(() {
      //     progress = value1 / value2;
      //   });
      // });
      // if (Platform.isIOS) {
      //   await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(saveFile.path,
      //       isReturnPathOfIOS: true);
      // }
      File savedFile = File(directory.path + "/$fileName");
      var savedPath = directory.path + "/$fileName";
      print('$savedPath');
      print('$savedFile');
      savedFile.writeAsBytesSync(byteList);
      if (savedPath != null) {
        print('NO saved Path');
        // await Navigator.pushReplacement(
        //   context,
        //   MaterialPageRoute(
        //       builder: (context) => SharePage(
        //             imageFilebytes: pngBytes,
        //             imagePath: savedPath,
        //           )),
        // );
      } else {
        print("waiting for savedpath");
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
  }
}
```

did I made something wrong??

Answer (score 1):

```
This is worked to save the image. It can be useful for you.

Future<bool> saveFile(var byteList, BuildContext context) async {
Directory storageDir;
try {
if (await requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
storageDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

String newPath = '';
List<String> folders = storageDir.path.split('/');
for (int x = 1; x < folders.length; x++) {
String folder = folders[x];
if (folder != 'Android') {
newPath += '/' + folder;
} else {
break;
}
}
newPath = newPath + '/xyz';
storageDir = Directory(newPath);
} else {
if (await requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
storageDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
} else {
return false;
        }
      }
      if (!await storageDir.exists()) {
        await storageDir.create(recursive: true);
      }
if (await storageDir.exists()) {
        //List<int> bytesSync = widget.pickedImage.readAsBytesSync();
        DateTime date = DateTime.now();
        String baseFileName = 'abc' + date.toString() + ".jpg";
        File savedFile = File(storageDir.path + "/$baseFileName");
        savedPath = storageDir.path + "/$baseFileName";
        savedFile.writeAsBytesSync(byteList);
        if (savedPath != null) {
          await Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SharePage(
                        imageFilebytes: pngBytes,
                        imagePath: savedPath,
                      )));
        } else {
          print("waiting for savedpath");
        }
        return true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply I tried as much as possible to implement the same... but Now I reached to another problem... I created the Folder in the location i wanted... also the file is already saved in the new folder...but the main issue is that the files are 0Bytes and can't be opened... I don't know if you can check my code

Comment: I think there are some issues when you save the file means may be some issues save file method. I add this link maybe it's useful for you. Try to change the save method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645917/flutter-download-file-to-phone-download-directory